# How to reference properties in an object to reevaluate them every time

Tags: c#, properties

I tried using a dictionary to map some `enum` to a number of `bool` properties:

```
private Dictionary<FooEnum, bool> isBarByFoo;

private Dictionary<FooEnum, bool> IsBarByFoo
{
    get
    {
        return isBarByFoo ?? (isBarByFoo = new Dictionary<FooEnum, bool>
        {
            { FooEnum.Foo1, IsBar1 },
            { FooEnum.Foo2, IsBar2 },
            { FooEnum.Foo3, IsBar3 }
        });
    }
}

private bool IsBar1 => SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime1();
private bool IsBar2 => SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime2();
private bool IsBar3 => SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime3();
```

However, this approach doesn't work, because the properties are simply evaluated once when the dictionary is created and saved as value type - turns out I misunderstood the way properties work.

Is it possible to store properties in a dictionary in a way that evaluates them every time they're looked up, or can you suggest a different solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: What about exposing [Indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) instead?

Comment: Why not return a new dictionary each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution may be to forget the dictionary and just use a method to get the value:

```
private bool GetIsBarByFoo(FooEnum foo)
{
    switch (foo)
    {
        case FooEnum.Foo1:
           return SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime1();
        case FooEnum.Foo2:
           return SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime2();
        case FooEnum.Foo3:
           return SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime3();
        default:
           return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
    private Dictionary<FooEnum, Func<bool>> isBarByFoo;

    private Dictionary<FooEnum, Func<bool>> IsBarByFoo
    {
        get
        {
            return isBarByFoo ?? (isBarByFoo = new Dictionary<FooEnum, Func<bool>>
            {
                { FooEnum.Foo1, SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime1},
                { FooEnum.Foo2, SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime2},
                { FooEnum.Foo3, SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime3}
            });
        }
    }

    private bool SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime1() => true;
    private bool SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime2() => false;
    private bool SomeConditionsThatChangeOverRuntime3() => true;
```

When you get a the value of the dictionary by `IsBarByFoo[FooEnum.Foo1]()` you get the desired value

Comment: the properties are more involved than the one-liners I used in the example, and can potentially have setters at some point - so I can't just replace them with methods

Comment: Well, that is what you asked for ;)

Comment: @j4_ what do you mean by one-liners? the private methods?